# EM algorithm for multivariate gaussian with diagonal covariance matrix

Tags: clustering, multivariate-normal-distribution, expectation-maximization, model-based-clustering

Ok so quick question.
Say I need to use the EM-algorithm to estimate the parameters of a multivariate gaussian

$$
f_{k}\left(x ; \theta_{k}\right)=\frac{1}{(2 \pi)^{P / 2}|V|} \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(x-\mu_{k}\right)^{\prime} V^{-1}\left(x-\mu_{k}\right)\right),
$$
where $V=\operatorname{diag}\left(\sigma_{1}, \sigma_{2}, \ldots, \sigma_{P}\right)$, and $|V|=\prod_{p=1}^{P} \sigma_{p} .$  (P is the number of variables)

Now since we have a diagonal covariance matrix, can I simply estimate the parameters by doing a regular old GMM EM-algorithm for each of the P variables individually? So basically doing it P times and combining the output afterward.

I am attempting to replicate the results of [this](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume8/pan07a/pan07a.pdf) paper. The dataset has j=1,...,n observations, p=1,...P variables and k=1,..,K clusters. The aim is to do variable selection.
Data was simulated as follow

There are a total of P = 1000 variables with the first
150 effective while the other 850 as noise variables in forming two clusters. Specifically, there
were n = 100 observations with 85 in one cluster and 15 in the other: the first 150 variables were
iid from N(0,1) for the first cluster, whereas they were iid from N(1.5,1) for the second cluster;
the remaining 850 variables were all iid from N(0,1) for either cluster. Hence, there were 150
informative attributes and 850 noise ones.

Comment: The reason why I actually want to do this is because I am working with a data set that has 1000 variables. So when doing the EM-algorithm for a multivariate gaussian I end up with values so close to zero that R or SAS makes them equal to 0. So I thought maybe if my reasoning above is not so far off, I can fix my little problem.

Comment: You don't have incomplete data so the EM algorithm is neither necessary nor appropriate for this problem. Also you need to describe the data and model more completely. What is $k$? How many data vectors do you observe? What is the from of $\mu_k$? We can make guesses but it would be better if we didn't need to.

Comment: @GordonSmyth I have updated my post.

Comment: Hope this makes more sense. Apologies I was trying to keep the post short and sweet.